# Python Discord Bot won't send private message on member join

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Okay, so I want my Bot to send a PM to everyone who joins my Discord server, after looking through Stackoverflow and the Documentation, I can not come up with the reason for this not working as intended. There are no error lines or similar.

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import ffmpeg

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='§')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    await member.send("Dies ist ein Test, begeben Sie sich in Deckung!")


bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: Events never take `ctx` as the argument, also you need intents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the [Member-Intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.members) for that to trigger.

The function parameter is also `member` not `ctx` as per [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join).

Check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) for basic usage of Intents.

Comment: Please flag this question as a duplicate instead of answering, there are tons of questions like this one, we don't need more